# Bits stream reading order

Tags: java, java-io

I've read in manual:

> For bit-oriented delivery, the bit
>   order for the byte stream format is
>   specified to start with the MSB of the
>   first byte, proceed to the LSB of the
>   first byte, followed by the MSB of the
>   second byte, etc.

In my application I have to cope with bits.
(for example I have decimal number 5, in binary format it looks like 00000101)
So, is that means (according to manual) that order of bits I read is

```
<= 0 <= 0 <= 0 <= 0 <= 0 <= 1 <= 0 <= 1 (first read bit I read is 0, second is 0 etc....)
```

or it means such order of reading bits:

```
<= 1 <= 0 <= 1 <= 0 <= 0 <= 0 <= 0 <= 0 (first read bit I read is 1, second is 0 etc....)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- MSB: Most significant bit
- LSB: Least significant bit

So for 5 (0000_0101) the bit on the left (representing 2<sup>7</sup>) is "most significant" and the bit on the right (representing 2<sup>0</sup>) is the "least significant".  Therefore, yes, expect 0 to be the first bit.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the default methods for reading and writing streams of bytes will automatically default to network byte-order, so you're probably good to go.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm working with low level parsing of byte stream, so I've to understand order of bits in bytes.

Comment: I don't think you do. Just use the calls that return you single bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If the first bytes in your stream are `0x7D,0x01`, then the stream of bits begins `0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1`.

Comment: @stem: i didnt understand  0x7D,0X01 . kindly can you explain.

Comment: @Suresh: If the first byte in the stream has hexadecimal value `7D` (= decimal 125) and the second has hexadecimal value `01` (= decimal value 1), then the stream of bits begins `0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1`. Is that any clearer?

Comment: @Suresh: Look, firstly you read one byte from ByteInputStream, it would be 0x7D. And if the bit order for the byte stream format is specified to start with the MSB of the byte, proceed to the LSB of the byte, you can say that bit order in this byte is 01111101. In the opposite situation you have to interpret such bit order in the byte 10111110

Comment: The "bits order in byte" specifies order of extracting bits from byte - from the tail or from the head.

Comment: thanks all  for explanation. how do you determine the byte u received is big endian or small endian?

Answer (score 1):

Byte order is mostly referred to as endian-ness.  You have big-endian systems and little-endian systems.

Big endian you have the Most Significant Bit first and in Little Endian, the least significant bit is first.

Most network traffic is big endian.  A X86 machine is always little-endian.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is more info about endian-ness

Comment: This is a bit misleading. Just because an X86 machine is little-endian, any RFC compliant network traffic will still be in "network byte order" - i.e. big-endian.